# iOS UIImagePickerController shows wrong button after locking phone

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an app with `take photo` functionality (like Instagram application).
I use `UIImagePickerController` with source type is equal to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` to take photo.

After I present `UIImagePickerController` it has one default button: 'Cancel'. After user takes photo there are two buttons: 'Retake' and 'Ready'. But if user lock a screen and unlock it again - there is only 1 button: 'Cancel' and the rest of UI is unresponsive (you cannot touch to take photo button again).

Is iOS specific problem or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I think it's ios 8 bug.
If you open standard contacts app and click take photo, the same issue occurs.

Comment: I found the issue http://openradar.appspot.com/18309885